# Pinball with velocity vector

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

A pinball moving in a plane with velocity **s** bounces (in a purely elastic impact) from a baffle whose endpoints are **p** and **q**. What is the velocity vector after the bounce?

The author has given the following answer to this question. Would any member of MSE tell me how does the highlighted terms relate to the velocity before and after the bounce?

[image: pinball velocity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the standard way of resolving a vector into components along perpendicular axes.  $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ are defined as perpendicular unit vectors.  $s.\hat u$, which is better written as $s \cdot \hat u$, is the length of the projection of $s$ along $\hat u$ so $(s\cdot \hat u)\hat u+(s\cdot \hat v)\hat v$ is $s$ resolved into components in that coordinate system.